# Gamemaker onscreen controls for android

Tags: android, sdk

I have been developing a few games on game maker like platformer and scrolling shooter. I recently got GameMaker Studio and was wondering how do you setup onscreen controls. For now i just want to have a jump button setup. I know how to setup controls for the keyboard if this can be of any help.

I have searched Google for tutorials but found none. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or something for reference.

Comment: I'm not surprised that there isn't much on Gamemaker Studio on Google since it would be a third-party API. I haven't used Gamemaker myself, but is the control API reliant on Gamemaker or does it use Android's?

Comment: I think it relies on gamemaker

Answer (score 1):

It's called virtual keys, you can read the GameMaker: Studio documentation for virtual keys here: http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/mouse,%20keyboard%20and%20other%20controls/virtual%20keys/index.html

or you can watch this tutorial on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wes7V-fOqD0

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

To create a button for android:

1. Create a sprite that you will press to jump
2. Create an object for that sprite
3. Create a left button pressed event
4. Add a code and write in whatever you want it to do

An example is you are using physics and you want to jump

```
    with(obj_player){
        if (place_meeting(x,y+1,obj_platform){
phy_apply_impulse(enter figures to jump more on help screen)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are things in Game Maker such as *virtual onscreen keys* that will mimic a key press on PC. You can look them up in Game Maker's help files. Hope this helps.